# Deploy list item with site collection url in XML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I deploy a list definition and instance by using XML to a Sharepoint 2010 site collection. There are some list items I create in the `Elements.xml` of the instance and everything works fine.

Now I have an URL field in the definition which I want to fill with an URL to the current site collection where the feature has been activated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="List" TemplateType="10020" Url="Lists/List">
    <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="UrlField"> 
          HOW TO INSERT THE SITE COLLECTION URL HERE? 
          </Field>
          ...
```

There are several versions I tried to insert:

- **http://myserver/myurl** An absolute URL works, of course, but is useless as the solution will be installed on different servers
- **~SiteCollection/myurl** This would have been be my first guess but unfortunately it does not work (error message invalid url on activation)
- **/myurl** This would work if the site collection is always the root **/** which is not true (as it could be under /websites/ for example)

Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't tried these, but worth a shot: `{SiteCollection}/myUrl`, or even `../myUrl`, `../../myUrl`. Otherwise you could update  the values in a ListAdded event receiver.

Comment: The `../myUrl` is an *invalid url* as well (on activation) but I will try the {SiteCollection} tomorrow, thank you!